# Validating Maven pom.xml when boolean is a property

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

If I have a `pom.xml` like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <resource.filtering>true</resource.filtering>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>${resource.filtering}</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>environment.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Eclipse marks the `<filtering>${resource.filtering}</filtering>` line with a validation error, because the schema tells it this should be a `boolean`, and that doesn't look like a `boolean`.  I would rather not shut off the `pom.xml` validation, and it's annoying to see the error on the project.  My goal is to be able to control whether resource filtering occurs based on Maven profiles.  Is there a way of doing this that passes Eclipse's validation?  I'm using Eclipse Luna (4.4).

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908258/eclipse-shows-errors-in-pom-xml-file-cvc-datatype-valid-1-2-1-myvar-is-no), and even tried filing a [bug report with the Eclipse team](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=458440). The answer I got was, "This is a result of an inherent conflict between the xsd that describes the pom format, and the aims of the pom file." So other than turning off validation, there isn't much one can do about these error messages.