# Eclipse shows errors in pom.xml file: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${MYVAR}' is not a valid value for 'boolean'

Tags: eclipse, validation, maven, pom.xml

I have a Maven project that builds fine on the command line. I want to edit the project files in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, but when I load the project, it reports the following errors in my pom.xml file:

> cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${MYVAR}' is not a valid value for 'boolean'
>
> cvc-type.3.1.3: The value of '${MYVAR}' of element 'enabled' is not valid.

This problem looks similar to [Validating Maven pom.xml when boolean is a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412567/validating-maven-pom-xml-when-boolean-is-a-property), which doesn't have any answers yet. While I can compile via Maven on the command line, it is annoying that Eclipse constantly reports these as errors. Is there any way to get rid of these errors without disabling the validation of the rest of the pom.xml file?

According to http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties I'm referencing the `MYVAR` property correctly.

Here are the relevant contents of my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.mydomain</groupId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <spring-version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <MYVAR>false</MYVAR>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>internal_repo</id>
      <name>my internal repository for offline use</name>
      <url>file://${INT_REPO_HOME}/java/maven_repo</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>${MYVAR}</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>${MYVAR}</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Just a doubt, is your eclipse setted with a JDK or a JRE?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, my Eclipse is setup to use jdk.1.7.0_71.

Comment: One thing I can't figure out is that there is no error reported on my `INT_REPO_HOME` reference. This is an environment variable, so I think that should be referenced as `${env.INT_REPO_HOME}`, according to the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties). Eclipse doesn't complain about it, and Maven finds the repo the way it is currently written. Perhaps it just passes the url to the command line which resolves the variable?

Comment: Are you using the m2e plugin or the external maven installation. If it is the internal, change it to the external and if it keep showing the error, add the parameters -X and -e for debugging

Comment: @JorgeCampos, I figured out how to change the installation from the embedded one to my external one, but where do I add the -X and -e parameters? Where does the debug output go?

Comment: After changed the maven installation you click with the right button on your project -> Run as -> Maven Build... (with the three dots) then you add the commands: install -e -X and click on Run button

Comment: @JorgeCampos, Thanks for the clarification. I did that, but I didn't see any references to the error I'm seeing in the debug build output. I would rather not post the whole output here. Is there anything I should be looking for in particular?

Comment: Yes, for the error class (stacktrace) that raised it. It should give a clue in where to find the solution. Another thing that I remember is your computer connected to the internet?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, Searching for errors in the output found nothing, and there were no stacktraces. So that seems like a dead end.

My computer is connected to the internet, but what does that have to do with this validation issue? The whole point of the way I setup my pom.xml file is to redirect Maven to use a local repository, instead of the one available on the internet.

Comment: A pom.xml is an XML file which is normally added with headers that validate the xml through an XSD file. Sometimes this `CVC` errors occurs when there is no connection so the XML can't be validated. On your pom.xml it is here: `xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"`. Another thing that I've just notice. Where is the `MYVAR` variable on your pom.xml ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, I am connected to the internet, and I verified that I can reach the xsd. Also, I updated my pom.xml example so it matches the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse is validating the XSD of the POM which says that this XML element is of type boolean.

Valid values for boolean are true/false so when it sees ${MYVAR} it raises a validation error... because the plugin of Eclipse doesn't do the variable translation from "${MYVAR}" to "false".

However if you do a mvn install it works with no problem, which means that the pom is correct.

Conclusion, this is an Elipse plugin issue so you can only ignore it.

Comment: So it sounds like your answer is, "No, there's no way to get rid of these errors in Eclipse." That's a disappointing answer, even if it is correct.

Comment: You can only cancel eclipse xml validation but I don't recommend you to do ir really. I suffer similar issues working with maven+android+eclipse. I recommend you to open a ticket to Eclipse. If you found my answer correct, please vote up :-P

Comment: When I asked this question I was afraid that this was going to be the answer. I'll open a ticket with Eclipse, and I awarded your answer with the bounty. I don't want to leave xml validation turned off, but now I'm curious. How do you do that?

Comment: Right click on your project --> properties --> Validation, then search for XML options like syntax validation, schema validation, etc.

Comment: That option didn't disable the errors. I haven't been able to find any place that does disable those errors.

Comment: Never mind. I turned off the wrong thing. I had to check the "Enable project specific settings" and then un-check the box in the Build column for "XML Validator" for the errors to go away. I don't think I'm going to keep that one turned off, though.

Comment: The Eclipse development team [responded to my issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=458440), and basically said, "This is a result of an inherent conflict between the xsd that describes the pom format, and the aims of the pom file." So other than turning off validation, there isn't much one can do about these error messages.

Answer (score 1):

i think that this is a timeing/order problem. maven first trys to build the whole project model before it executes is. so to collect all pom.xml to construct the whole model of the project it uses the repositories. and AFTER this it uses the properties and replaces all the variables for the effective project model (pom.xml)

if you use the ${MYVAR} outside the  definition it should be no problem.. right?

Comment: It must be an Eclipse plugin issue, as @Carlos suggested, since it does resolve the ${MYVAR} correctly when I run `mvn install`. It correctly reads the variable and uses only my internal repo when `MYVAR` is false, and I get no build errors.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is an Eclipse issue, because Eclipse developers refuse to acknowledge the difference between a templated XML and a runtime XML.  Only in the latter case does validation matter.

They have a good concept of allowing you to turn validations on/off, or converting some to warnings.  But, in this case, there this option does not exist.

People have suggested that you can turn this validation off, but I've tried to know avail.  Personally, I have no interest in any XSD validation being done by Eclipse.

The only option I'm aware of is to lobby https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/